# Unable to generate Elmah.axd file of Elmah logging with Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, elmah, webapi2

I have created Web API only. In that I want to use Elmah Logging. I have installed Nuget package of it. But when I try to access Elmah.axd file from browser it gives me an error : 404 Not Found. And that file is not generated. I have followed [this](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/) link.

Do I need to do anything additional to generate/access this file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the tutorial you have linked to. I just created a new Web API project and installed ELMAH. /elmah.axd is available. I would be very interested in seeing your web.config if you can update the question with that? Also, you can try to validate your web.config using the ELMAH Configuration Validator here: https://elmah.io/tools/configvalidator

Comment: It is working fine now. I have installed another package Elmah.contrib.Webapi and it worked for me.

Comment: One more thing I found to keep older error logs in axd file. I do not know how it works. But I have created one folder named ErrorLog. And it works fine. I do not know whether you have mention this in your article or not. But this is good.

Comment: /elmah.axd should work out of the box when installing ELMAH. Elmah.Contrib.WebApi is for logging errors from Web API and don't have anything to do with /elmah.axd.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification.